# trying to compile the program which generates sha1 hashes

Tags: c, gcc, hash, mingw, sha1

I am trying to compile this program https://gist.github.com/jrabbit/1042021
I am using this https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/satsolver/11.2/sha1_8h_source.html sha1.h file. However if I try to compile the program gcc gives me the following error (gcc on windows)

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.start
up+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

gcc did not recognise type u_int32_t so I changed them to unit32_t in sha1.c code

What could be wrong there?

Comment: The error says you have no `main` function.

Comment: yes main() function is commented as @HolyBlackCat said.   try to uncomment it. 
 Remove #if 0 on line 251 and  #endif on line 276.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library doesn't have `main` function. Any C program must have a `main` function to compile.

So either you create a `main.c` file and include the library in it.
Or **in line 251 of `sha1.c` change `#if 0` to `#if 1` which will open the template main function included in the library.**

Note that the template 'main` function has some bugs. Replace it with something like that:

```
#define BUFSIZE 10

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SHA1_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char hash[20], buf[BUFSIZE];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<BUFSIZE;i++)
    {
        buf[i] = i + '0';
        printf("%i", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    SHA1Init(&ctx);
    for(i=0;i<BUFSIZE;i++)
        SHA1Update(&ctx, buf + i, 1);
    SHA1Final(hash, &ctx);

    printf("SHA1=");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```